# Get Okta Token details from java api

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have created Okta token by following the steps below.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/getting_a_token
Now i would like get this token details from Okta through Java code,
I am using Okta-Java-SDk, but not finding any API which can give details like Name, Creation date and other details that i see on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't have a public API that will get token for use with Okta's management API.

Comment: Is there any other possible way to get details. My requirement is rotate the Key after certain number of days, so i need to send alaram Just before, to inform Key is alreadt these many days old, please update new one. It would be helpful if you can give some information for my requirement,

Comment: In the future, we will support oauth based tokens which should help with this.